# joomla : authentication

Tags: authentication, joomla

I have made a folder in joomla directory. In this folder I have some file.

I want to authenticate these files from direct access using URL by name?

How can it be achieved?

Comment: You can use .htaccess for it:

look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728976/how-to-deny-access-to-a-file-in-htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but you can create a PHP script (let's call it `joomla-auth.php`) containing this:

```
<?php

define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');

if (JFactory::getUser()->id == 0)
   die("Access denied: login required.");

?>
```

Then, at the top of PHP scripts that need Joomla authentication, do:

```
<?php
include 'joomla-auth.php';
?>
```

If you have a PHP script, and you need to get information about the authenticated user, use `JFactory::getUser()` .  If you have an `.html` file, you can change the extension to `.php` and add the 3 lines above to the top.

Chances are, creating a component or module is the "right way" to do what you're trying to do.  However, I can't advise you on that because this is a lesson I still need to learn myself.  You should also look into Jumi, which lets you embed PHP, HTML, JavaScript, etc. files directly into articles using a syntax like this:

```
{jumi myfile.html}{/jumi}
```