# How to deny access to a file in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file:

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Protect the htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Protect log.txt
<Files ./inscription/log.txt>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes
```

I am trying to forbid visitors to access the following file:

```
domain.example/inscription/log.txt
```

but what I have above does not work: I can still access the file from the browser remotely.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Within an htaccess file, the scope of the `<Files>` directive only applies to that directory (I guess to avoid confusion when rules/directives in the htaccess of subdirectories get applied superceding ones from the parent).

So you can have:

```
<Files "log.txt">  
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

For Apache 2.4+, you'd use:

```
<Files "log.txt">  
  Require all denied
</Files>
```

In an htaccess file in your `inscription` directory. Or you can use mod_rewrite to sort of handle both cases deny access to htaccess file as well as log.txt:

```
RewriteRule /?\.htaccess$ - [F,L]

RewriteRule ^/?inscription/log\.txt$ - [F,L]
```

Comment: If your using IIS, do this in the web.config file instead.

Comment: Using the rewrite rules denies my own code from accessing the contents of *.txt. How would you get around this?

Comment: "the scope of the `<Files>` directive only applies to that directory" - no it doesn't. It applies to that directory _and_ all subdirectories below it. So `<Files "log.txt">` will catch `/log.txt` _and_ `/inscription/log.txt`.

Comment: Can you update this answer since `Order Allow,Deny` is deprecated in 2.4?

Answer (score 21):

**Strong pattern matching** — This is the method that I use here at Perishable Press. Using strong pattern matching, this technique prevents external access to any file containing “**.hta**”, “**.HTA**”, or any case-insensitive combination thereof. To illustrate, this code will prevent access through any of the following requests:

- .htaccess
- .HTACCESS
- .hTaCcEsS
- testFILE.htaccess
- filename.HTACCESS
- FILEROOT.hTaCcEsS

..etc., etc. Clearly, this method is highly effective at securing your site’s HTAccess files. Further, this technique also includes the fortifying “**Satisfy All**” directive. Note that this code should be placed in your domain’s root HTAccess file:

```
# STRONG HTACCESS PROTECTION
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</Files>
```

Comment: I get a 500 internal server error when using this code. Any idea why? I'm using Wordpress.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to just disallow users from accessing dotfiles? Using something like `<Files ~"^\..*">`.

Comment: Need a space between tilde and first quote mark—at least for me I needed it. ~ SPACE "

Comment: I obtained the same behavior disabling .files: 
<filesMatch "^\..*">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</FilesMatch>

Comment: "containing “.hta”, “.HTA”, or any case-insensitive combination" - But that's only necessary if you are running on a case-insensitive filesystem like Windows, and it's unlikely you'd be running Apache on Windows in a production environment. `^\..*` - You don't need the trailing `.*` if you just want to block dot-files. `^\.` will do the job (and is shorter and more efficient). `^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])` - Likewise, you don't need the `^.*` prefix here, for the same reason a trailing `.*` is not required (and not used).

Comment: Please give credit when you copy/paste [someone else's work](https://perishablepress.com/improve-site-security-by-protecting-htaccess-files/comment-page-2/).

Answer (score 18):

I don't believe the currently accepted answer is correct. For example, I have the following `.htaccess` file in the root of a virtual server (apache 2.4):

```
<Files "reminder.php">
require all denied
require host localhost
require ip 127.0.0.1
require ip xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa
</Files>
```

This prevents external access to `reminder.php` which is in a subdirectory.
I have a similar `.htaccess` file on my Apache 2.2 server with the same effect:

```
<Files "reminder.php">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from localhost
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa
</Files>
```

I don't know for sure but I suspect it's the attempt to define the subdirectory specifically in the `.htaccess` file, *viz* `<Files ./inscription/log.txt>` which is causing it to fail.  It would be simpler to put the `.htaccess` file in the same directory as `log.txt` i.e. in the `inscription` directory and it will work there.

Answer (score 4):

Place the below line in your .htaccess file and replace the file name as you wish

```
RewriteRule ^(test\.php) - [F,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

On Apache 2.4, if you want to deny access to a specific file (or URL-path) in a subdirectory then you can use an Apache expression in an `<If>` container. For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/inscription/log.txt'">
    Require all denied
</If>
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html

Answer (score -5):

Well you could use the `<Directory>` tag
for example:

```
<Directory /inscription>
  <Files log.txt>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

Do not use `./` because if you just use `/` it looks at the root directory of your site.

For a more detailed example visit http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html

Comment: But a `<Directory>` container is not permitted in `.htaccess`. In `.htaccess`, the `.htaccess` file itself is the "_Directory_ container" (per-directory config file).

Comment: Well then you could use the Redirect. `Redirect /inscription/log.txt access_denied.html` This will redirect the user to `access_denied.html` if the user goes to `inscription/log.txt` in the inscription directory.