# Override file request with Symfony @Route

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing

I'm new with Symfony and I'm working on a test project to improve my knowledge. Actually I'm learning [Routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html) and what I'm trying to do is to deny access if a file with `.disabled` extension is requested. I'm talking about files placed in `web` directory. So, for example, file located at `web/config.php.disabled` cannot be executed/downloaded.

Then I created a route like this

```
/**
 * @Route("{req}disabled", name="denyAccess", requirements={"req"=".+"})
 */
public function denyAccessAction(Request $request, $req)
{
    return new Response('Access denied');
}
```

and is working fine when I request a file that doesn't exist (e.g. http://my.website/file.php.disabled). But when I request an existing file, the route doesn't work and I can download that file without problems. So I guess requesting an existing file placed in web directory will override any route.

How can I make my route have higher priority than a requested file in web directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Web server configuration problem. In a basic Symfony Web configuration, in order to serve the files contained in your web/ directory, your Web server does not call PHP nor Symfony. Your Symfony application is only the fallback if the file is not found for the given URL.

Now the question is: what are you using as a Web proxy ? Nginx, Apache, HAProxy ?

If you are using Nginx, you should have something like this in your configuration:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^/app_dev\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/phpX.X-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
}
```

In the first block, `try_files` makes exactly what I told you: First it will try to return the file associated to the given $url, then if it's not found, it falls back to app_dev.php with the same routing parameters. It is then caught by the second block, which forwards the request to PHP.

So, for your particular use case, I suggest you add a block to deny users that would request a file with ".disabled". In Nginx, this is done easily:

```
location ~ \.disabled/?$ {
    return 403;
}
```

For other Web server technologies, just check the docs to know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

`web/` is a resource folder and Symfony does not have control over this one through Routing System (unless the URI does not exist).

If you have trying to deny access to `config.php` it is already done inside him:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
    exit('This script cannot be run from the CLI. Run it from a browser.');
}

if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
    '127.0.0.1',
    '::1',
))) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('This script is only accessible from localhost.');
}
```

So, you can access from localhost only (development environment), but from external host, this deny access.

---

On the other hand, you can deny access to others files by using the Web Server configuration:

- Apache (`.htaccess` file) ([How to deny access to a file in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728976/how-to-deny-access-to-a-file-in-htaccess))
- Nginx (http://www.queryadmin.com/1071/deny-access-sensitive-files-nginx/)