# Deny access to some subdirectories via .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

This is a common question, but I'm a bit stupid so other's methods didn't work out for me. I want to deny access to following subdirectories (note: main site is located like this `http://localhost/en/` and every subdir is staring with `/en/` where `.htaccess` file is located): `reg_auth_rec_del/ajax/` (and all it's files), `media/parts/`, `media/scripts/`, `media/translations/`. But the thing is that all these files are used on all pages (for example `media/parts/footer.php` is used on all pages and can be viewable on pages like `index.php` and others. So I want to prevent user from viewing all these files directly.

I mean so I don't want them to be directly viewable.

Now, I'm just using this way, but I think that it's not a good way to handle things:

```php
$admins = array("192.168.0.100", "192.168.0.101", "192.168.0.102");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if(in_array($ip ,$admins, true)){
    $_SESSION['PERMISSIONS'] = "ADMIN";
} else {
    $_SESSION['PERMISSIONS'] = "USER";
}

//So if $_SESSION['PERMISSIONS'] == "USER", I can decide if I'd ike to open access to some files, and
//if the file can be viewable by user
```

Comment: I don't know the `if(defined...)` trick.

Comment: i think this other post could help http://stackoverflow.com/a/11729748/6208463

Comment: *how* are they used on pages? If a file like *media/translations/en-US.php* is simply included in a header PHP file you can just deny access (`Deny from all` in Apache 2.2, `Require all denied` in 2.4) but if *media/scripts* contains JavaScript files that are used on the front end you'll have to allow access or they won't be able to run client-side; best you can do there is disable directory indexing.

Comment: @CD001 Yes, scripts are connected to files like this `<script src="media/scripts/jquery.js"></script>` and parts are included to my other pages. And I want to deny access to `ajax` folder (all except `helper.php`) just in case if server crashes to prevent users from viewing all session data

Comment: If you put these other files in a folder outside of the webroot there is no way they can hit them in the browser..  eg  point apache to set this as the webroot `/mysite/public` and then put the partial templates in `/mysite/templates/`

Comment: *"I mean so I don't want them to be directly viewable."* - you can't really prevent that though; if a JS file (for instance) can be loaded in through a `<script>` tag it can be directly viewed.

Comment: JS has to be public in order for the browser to load it. no way you can hide them. but you can hide php files

Comment: @JasonJoslin Here we go. Updated.

Comment: does you mean those files are included internally? `<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/en/(?:media/(?:parts|scripts|translations)|reg_auth_rec_d‌​el/ajax)/#"> Require all denied </If>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is as @JasonJoslin suggested in comments, move the PHP files outside your document root. You can still include them in other PHP files.

For Javascript files, style sheets, and images, there is no way to deny access, because these files are included in the HTML responses, and the clients must be able to load them somehow.

---

If you want to keep files inside the document root and forbid access anyway, you can either use the old style [`Order`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order), and `Allow`/`Deny`, or apply the new directives as described in [Access control](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access). Put an .htaccess file in subdirectories `reg_auth_rec_del/ajax`, etc.

```
Require all denied
```

This should deny access to the directories and all their subdirectories as well.

Comment: What about `RedirectMatch`? Is there any solution using it?

Comment: `RedirectMatch` is only useful, if you want to send another resource instead.