# I want one php file to protect from normal user but let it to be used by cron job

Tags: php, cron

I am using ooowebhost. I have a PHP file, which I want that normal user should not be able to run it except cron job. 
As this file is inside public folder so it hard to protect from normal user but let cron job executor to access it.

Comment: I want to secure one php file from normal user but let it to be accessible for corn job executor.

Comment: You can probs achieve this with .htaccess please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728976/how-to-deny-access-to-a-file-in-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

you can block your script executing from browser, but run through cron/cli.

Method 1:
Add below line in the start of the script,

```
if (php_sapi_name() !='cli') exit;
```

OR

Method 2:

Add in the start of the script,

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != 'yourSecretAgent') exit;
```

replace agent ,

Thanks,
M.AkberKhan