# Make my page work for certain place

Tags: javascript, html, css, vs-web-site-project

I am under developing a game website i would like to know how to make **only certain point of my website to work**? and the rest should be disabled!

Comment: Easy: break the rest of it.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Assuming you gonna host it on a apache webserver, you could block some directorys with a .htacces file like asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728976/how-to-deny-access-to-a-file-in-htaccess)

Comment: I think you're making a *lot* of unfounded assumptions about the question.